# iOS Safari + CSS calc() + CSS transition = Instant Crash

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-transitions

When I try to use `left: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);` (assuming that `left: 0;` is initial state) it works in iOS 6.0.1 just fine. But when I do the same with `transition: left 1s linear;` it instantly crashes Safari, every single time. Is it known bug or am I doing something wrong?

It also doesn't work in Safari 5 (no reaction). But it works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It's obviously a bug, try reporting it, see [How should I submit bug reports and feature requests?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-should-i-submit-bug-reports-and-feature-requests) on Ask Different.

Comment: Safari 5 doesn't support calc so Safari mobile won't either

Comment: Safari 6 supports calc already but it crashes when you use this with transition.

Comment: Man, my whole afternoon was spent discovering this little bug. Thanks for this.

Comment: Confirming what @Atadj said, Safari 6.0.5 (Desktop) crashes when -webkit-calc is used in conjunction with a CSS3 transition.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by initialising the property with anything but auto:

```
.menu {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s linear;
}

.menu-open .menu {
  left: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
  left: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this currently doesn't work on iOS. Looks like a Mobile Safari bug.

Answer (score 2):

This has been a WebKit bug for some time now. For now you can use JS to accomplish the same end effect.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers posted thus far worked for me.

What did work was working around the `calc` statement using negative margin:

```
#example {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had to do this to accomplish a similar task:

```
$('.modal').css({
  'height': $(window).height() - 40
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do something like this:

```
.class{
    left: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
    transition: margin-left 1s linear, right 1s linear;
}


.class.open {
    margin-left: -100%;
    right: 100px;
}
```

WARNING: Untested

Comment: i believe that's exactly what causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem after spending much time testing my responsive, not iOS mobile, design in Chrome. There were many "elastic" elements in place so I wanted a solution that could cover all of them at least for an early version.

If you're doing a responsive design using purely CSS a hack to keep it from at least crashing is:

```
@media (max-device-width: 1024px) {

* {
  -webkit-transition: width 0, top .8s !important;
  -moz-transition: width 0, top .8s !important;
  -o-transition: width 0, top .8s !important;
  transition: width 0, top .8s !important;
}
```

I wanted to keep the top positioning transitions in place, so had to do it this way.

This solution could be better as it will have some overlap with people using 1024 monitors & Android, but I did use *max-device-with* in place of *max-width* to avoid overlap with small windows. I'd assume that 1024 monitor users likely aren't using a modern browser, but would like to fix the Android overlap.

Answer (score 0):

put together this little test to see if it ever gets fixed. currently it crashes mac safari 6.0.5 and iOS safari.

http://jsbin.com/omexek/3/