# CSS3 Transition ( Vendor Prefixes) crashes Safari immediately

Tags: css, safari, crash

Here is the project I'm working on (code copied exactly except for names changed, etc.)

https://c9.io/schwigri/strange-crash/workspace/index.html

The div `#logo` has the style:

```
#logo {
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    -moz-transition: .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

This causes an immediate crash in Safari 6.0.5 on OS X 10.8.5.
If I remove these transitions it doesn't crash.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Safari has some trouble sometimes with `all`-property transitions.

Try this:

```
#logo {
    -webkit-transition: color .4s;
    -moz-transition: .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

**Edit:** After playing around with it some more, it's actually the combination of your usage of `-webkit-transition: all` and `-webkit-calc()` that's causing the problem. This is a bug in Safari, and in order to overcome it, you may need to use javascript to calculate your top margin instead of CSS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this insight; I can work around that! I wouldn't have known that.