# css transitions not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

If you look at my page http://debourg-dev.ch/crea/ you will see the transition effects on my links don't work in safari (tested on latest version on mac). My code is the following:

```
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It is working for me on Safari...

Comment: Try this all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s. Adding that 0s on the end was needed for ios6 ipad

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but again no difference

Answer (score 9):

It seems Safari has a bug and chokes on `transition: all;` (or just `transition: Xs;` because 'all' is the default property). It even crashes some versions of desktop and iOS Safari.

**SOLUTION**: Change it to `transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;`
(Or, of course any other property, just make sure it's not 'all'.)

It could also be a problem specifically with the transition being applied globally to anchor tags - read more [here](http://joelglovier.com/writing/solution-for-css-transitions-crashing-safari/)

More about Safari [crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987787/my-website-crashes-safari-both-desktop-and-ios-consistently)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130896/css3-transition-vendor-prefixes-crashes-safari-immediately)

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. 

I'll also note that this isn't consistent across style properties- I encountered a bug in MacOS Safari 13.1 where if `transition:all` is applied, Safari will not rerender certain properties like `outline` if they are the only property whose value is being changed. But adding other properties like `font-size` would trigger a repaint, with all transitions would be rendered, including the previously ignored `outline`.

Answer (score 0):

The transition appears to be working for me when running OSX 10.9.1 and Safari 7.0.1. If I had to guess, the issue is likely due to cacheing. Try clearing your cache and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Already tried clearing the cache and reseting safari, still not working. I'm also running OSX 10.9.1 and Safari Version 7.0.1 (9537.73.11)

Answer (score 0):

For Safari try the following:

```
-webkit-transition: 190ms width linear;
```

where width represents the property being changed, prevent use of `all` as different browsers interpret this differently and can cause issues especially in Safari browser.

Comment: Suprisingly instead of using transition: translateY(0) 1s; using your format fixed my Safari buggy animation problem