# Difference between transition: flex and -webkit-transition: all

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm studying https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days By Brad and Florin on Udemy.

At "Expanding Cards" project([live demo](https://50projects50days.com/projects/expanding-cards/)), the mentioned code in the video doesn't perform the cards transition smoothly. Then I found [Chad has fixed the issue](https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days/commit/086998ac4b173b09c3b95fb0dbb091c533b91cc0). People share the updated code everywhere, but I'd like to know how different they works exactly as I could not find the good information about it (i.e. Why "all" is required in this case, not just "flex"?). I'll appreciate if you explain, or share the links to the helpful information.

Removed code

```
transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
```

Added code

```
-webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;
```

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183413/flex-transition-in-safari

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
I also referred these, and understood "flex" doesn't work at Safari browsers [(1)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131664), "all" isn't required, rather it shall be avoided [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767037/css-transitions-not-working-in-safari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question.

- "flex" doesn't work at Safari browsers [(1)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131664)
- "all" isn't required, rather it shall be avoided [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767037/css-transitions-not-working-in-safari).